# Solving coupled integral + differential equations for ionoization and combination of gases near a star

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-physics, ionization-energy, nebulae

The following set of coupled differential + integral equations appear regularly in the literature (e.g Osterbrock, "Astrophysics of Gaseous Nebulae and Active Galactic Nebulae"):

$ n_H(r) \int_{\nu_0}^\infty \frac{L_v}{(4 \pi r^2 h \nu)} (\frac{\nu_0}{\nu})^3 e^{-\tau_\nu}d\nu  = Kn_e n_p  $

for a known constant K, with ${\nu_0}$ also known.

where we also have the equations

${\tau_\nu} = {\tau_0}(\frac{\nu}{\nu_0})^3 $

$\frac{d\tau_0}{dr} = Mn_H(r) $             (m known constant)

and $L_\nu = L\frac{\nu^3}{e^{k\nu} -1}$ where L and k are also known constants.

$n_e = n_p$

$n_e + n_H(r) = H$, another known constant

In Osterbrock's book he merely states that these equations may be solved computationally and moves on. At this source  here http://www.astro.gsu.edu/~crenshaw/4.Ionization.pdf it is claimed "since $\tau_0$ is a known function of $n_H(r)$ and r, the ionisation equilibrium equation can be integrated outwards for given $n_H(r)$ and r to obtain $\frac{n_p}{n_H(r)}$", but I'm not sure I completely understand what is meant by this - we want to solve the integral to find $n_H(r)$ but this itself appears in the integral through tau's dependency on it!

My end goal here is to find $n_H(r)$ as a function of r. My instinct so far is that some substitution should reduce the integral to a purely numerical figure (no $n_H(r)$ dependency) that can be computationally integrated out, but I've had no success with any of the obvious candidates.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What bothers you here? This is called a system of integro-differential equations. This can be solved using numerical methods.

Comment: You set all the parameters, and I will show the numerical method.

Comment: Thank you for the term - I had not heard it before, though have certainly solved many simpler examples - usually via a Laplace transform. I realise I am after some sort of numerical method to solve this, but don't see that it is tractable n its immediately given form, and so wonder if this transformsation of the integral equation may be appropriate here. It didn't work when I tried before but I may have made a mistake, so I'll give it another go.

Comment: By "the parameters", do you mean the parameters in the equations that I set to 1?

Comment: Do you suggest putting $h=H=k=L=M=\nu_0=1$? What about $\tau_0(0)$?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In general - no - I won't want to set those to 1, as I'm likely going to write a program to implement said numerical methods, and I may as well let it take these as inputs. Some of them are constant and some we should allow to take general input values - I will clarify this in my next comment

Comment: h = 6.626 x 10^-34 (Planck's constant), $\nu_0$ = 3.29 x 10^15, K should be allowed to take general values, M should be allowed to take general values, L should be allowed to take general values though it a constant multiple of $R^2$ (specifically $8\pi^2 \frac{h}{c^2}$, where c is speed of light, the radius which again is general. $\tau_0 (R)$  = 0, which should suffice for boundary conditions. k should also be allowed to take general values. Setting all  "should be allowed to take general values to 1" would still be very helpful as given the approach I can adapt!

Comment: In a numerical solution there cannot be a general value. You have to set a number.

Comment: Understood - but since the method will presmably (?) be the same irrespective of their values, and I may run the method for different combinations of values for these constants, I meant that simply showing it with these taking any given value would suffice as in a computer program I can refer to them by constant name which is fed as an input into the program. Perhaps for simplicity we should set all equal to 1 for this point and I can then adapt? For the R/L issue: let's have R = 1 and L defined accordingly as above.

Comment: I can recommend test data from http://www.astro.gsu.edu/~crenshaw/4.Ionization.pdf

Comment: That test data works fine - but surely the numerical method will be the same either way?